# Way to make date_select field be the date for all other date_select fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using a nested form I generated 5 `UserPrices` so users are filling out 5 of all of the same form fields:

**UserPricesController**

```
    def add_store_prices
        @a_new_user = User.new
        5.times do
            @a_new_user.user_prices.build
        end
    end
```

I have one field called :purchase_date which is a date_select (date dropdown menu) field:

```
<%= f.date_select :purchase_date %>
```

I want to use only one UserPrice date_select to be the date for the other 4 UserPrices, this way users don't have to select 5 date dropdown menus and can just select one only, is there a jquery plugin or javascript code to make this possible?

P.S.: This is how it looks right now, I want to get rid of the other 4 Date rows and just have one.

[image: As of now]

Comment: sorry you question is hard to understand

Comment: Do you know about on Ruby-on-Rails?

Comment: Well this question was aimed towards Ruby-on-Rails but I will edit it for jquery or javascript in general.

Comment: no im not totaly familiar with it, but UserPricesController code is understandable, its your last paragraph i cant fully understand what you need to try to help you

Comment: Oh ok, how about now? I edited the question.

Comment: If you always want one date, why not just have one date select for all rows? Then there's no need to keep them all in sync.

Comment: Another way without javascript is this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805352/how-to-update-a-models-attribute-with-a-virtual-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New version more generic, This will change any amount of date selects as long as you have a underscore and a integer at the end an begins at 1, for each selct id

```
<select id="purchase_date_month_1" onchange="changesPurchaseDates(this)"><option>10<option>12</select>
<select id="purchase_date_day_1" onchange="changesPurchaseDates(this)"><option>29<option>28</select>
<select id="purchase_date_year_1" onchange="changesPurchaseDates(this)"><option>2010<option>2011</select>
```

so the the remaining are

```
<select id="purchase_date_month_2">
<select id="purchase_date_day_2">
<select  id="purchase_date_year_2">

<select id="purchase_date_month_3">
<select id="purchase_date_day_3">
<select  id="purchase_date_year_3">
```

.... to the (N)th or 5th then you could use this function to select the first option which will change the remaining.

```
<script>

function changesPurchaseDates(n) {
var arr_purdate_selects = []; // object to store the select boxs

var nd = (n.id).slice(0,(n.id).lastIndexOf("_")); // slice off the remaining from last underscore

arr_purdate_selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select"); // store all found selects Diry i know
 // loop throught all selects
 for (var i = 1; i < arr_purdate_selects.length; i++) {
 // only if the ids match the change those
   if(nd == (arr_purdate_selects[i].id).slice(0,(arr_purdate_selects[i].id).lastIndexOf("_"))){
  document.getElementById(arr_purdate_selects[i].id).selectedIndex =     document.getElementById(nd+"_"+1).selectedIndex;
  }  
 }

}


 </script>
```

I hope this helps