# How to update a model's attribute with a virtual attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model named `UserPrice` which has the attribute `:purchase_date`(a date_select) in its table. With my form I can create multiple user_prices at once but for user convenience I made a virtual attribute inside of my `UserPrice` model called `:all_dates` that's also a date_select field and its job is to be the replacement of the `:purchase_dates` so users only have to select the `:all_dates` field for the date.

---

**Problem & Question**

The `:all_dates` field is not updating the  `:purchase_date` fields of my user_prices that are being created. **What do I need to do in order to get my `:all_dates` field to update the `:purchase_date` fields of my new `UserPrices`?**

**Does anyone have any tips on how to do this?**

---

**Parameters**

```
Parameters: 
"user_price"=> { 
"all_dates(2i)"=>"10", 
"all_dates(3i)"=>"27", 
"all_dates(1i)"=>"2011"
}, 
"user_prices"=>
{
"0"=>{"product_name"=>"Item1", "store"=>"Apple Store","price"=>"6"}, 
"1"=>{"product_name"=>"Item2", "store"=>"Apple Store", "price"=>"7"}
}, 
"commit"=>"Submit"}
```

---

**Code**

```
  class CreateUserPrices < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
       create_table :user_prices do |t|
          t.decimal :price
          t.integer :product_id
          t.date :purchase_date
          t.timestamps
        end
     end
  end
```

I took out the `:purchase_date` field so it isn't inside of the user_price loop.

```
<%= form_tag create_multiple_user_prices_path, :method => :post do %>
 <%= date_select("user_price", "all_dates" )  %>
   <% @user_prices.each_with_index do |user_price, index| %>
      <%= fields_for "user_prices[#{index}]", user_price do |up| %>
          <%= render "user_price_fields", :f => up %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>




class UserPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :price, :product_name, :purchase_date, :all_dates, :store
  attr_accessor :all_dates
  after_save :save_all_dates_to_user_prices
  composed_of :all_dates, :class_name => "DateTime",
    :mapping => %w(Time to_s),
    :constructor => Proc.new { |item| item },
    :converter => Proc.new { |item| item }

  def user_prices
    @user_prices = Array.new() { UserPrice.new }
  end

  protected

  def save_all_dates_to_user_prices 
     if !self.all_dates.nil?       
      self.user_prices.each {|up| up.purchase_date = self.all_dates if up.new_record?}
     end
  end


class UserPricesController < ApplicationController

 def new
    @user_prices = Array.new(5) { UserPrice.new }
 end

 def create_multiple
   @user_prices = params[:user_prices].values.collect { |up| UserPrice.new(up) }
   if @user_prices.all?(&:valid?)
     @user_prices.each(&:save!)
     redirect_to :back, :notice => "Successfully added prices."
   else
     redirect_to :back, :notice => "Error, please try again."
   end
end
```

Comment: Where is `all_dates` being populated? In the form? You should post your form.

Comment: @bricker :all_dates is posted in my form, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of trying to do in a model what is better left to the controller. All you're trying to do here is to auto-assign a certain attribute on creation from a parameter not directly tied to your model. But you're not even passing that extra parameter to the model anywhere - you're creating your model instances from the `user_prices` parts of the parameter hash, but the `user_price` sub-hash is not used anywhere. In any case, this is behavior that is more closely related to the view and action taken than the model, so keep it in the controller.

Try this:

1. Throw out the virtual attribute, and get rid of the whole `after_save` callback stuff
2. Throw away the `user_prices` method in your model
3. Change the `all_dates` attribute name back to `purchase_date` in the form

Then your parameter hash should look like this:

```
{"user_price"=> { 
  "purchase_date(2i)"=>"10", 
  "purchase_date(3i)"=>"27", 
  "purchase_date(1i)"=>"2011"
}, 
"user_prices"=>
{
  "0"=>{"product_name"=>"Item1", "store"=>"Apple Store","price"=>"6"}, 
  "1"=>{"product_name"=>"Item2", "store"=>"Apple Store", "price"=>"7"}
}}
```

All that's left to do is to merge the single `user_price` attributeS into each `user_prices` sub-hash in your `create_multiple` action. Replace the first line in that action with this:

```
@user_prices = params[:user_prices].values.collect do |attributes| 
  UserPrice.new(attributes.merge(params[:user_price])) 
end
```

Comment: Yes, Finally, thank you so much Thilo. To achieve want I wanted, yours was a far better  and understandable way. Thank you, everything is working how I wanted it to!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are even using that virtual attribute is there more to this implementation?  If you are just trying to save an associated model, you might simply want a `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_prices` in your User model

This works great and many developers use this method, so it's nice to know for working on other projects as well as for the people who might end up maintaining yours.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: The virtual attribute is for updating all of my :purchase_dates of my UserPrice's and the rails casts way of doing it different from how I did it. I will include more code so the picture is clearer.

Comment: I am just trying to figure out if their is a method like update_all that would update only those particular resources in my create action.

Comment: Okay I think I understand the "why" behind it now. I would probably do it the railscasts way and just use hidden fields on the form to let the "magic" of rails do it's thing.

But you could

`self.user_prices.each {|up| up.purchase_date = self.all_dates if up.new_record?}`

Comment: I get a mass assignment error when I try that following above code. Take a look at my updated section.

Comment: @JustinRoR, if you are okay with setting these attributes via mass-assignment you just need to add  `attr_accessible :attr1, :attr2, :attr3` to the model that they are on.

Comment: I changed around my whole question. Instead of doing it by a nested_form, I'm able to create UserPrices without taking the route. Now I am getting this undefined method and my code is pretty different now. You have any ideas?

Comment: JustinRoR, please post your exact error.  Ruby is famous for saying undefined method when the method does exist but you've got a null object (the null object doesn't have your methods). So please post details of error. Thx!

Comment: @Michael Durrant Ok, I rolled back to get back to my code I had before my revised question. You can see the error I have. It's weird because to me it seemed like its defined but for some reason its not.

Comment: check `<%= fields_for "user_prices[#{index}]", user_price do |up| %>' maybe it should be `user_price` ?

Comment: @Michael Durrant It's strange, the problem has dissapeared but the code I have to update the user_prices for the :all_dates attribute is not doing its job, It still remains blank. I edited my question, take a look at the Parameters.