# Getting NoMethodError, how do I define this method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using a virtual attribute called `:all_dates`  on my form . The point of this field is to replace the `:purchase_date` attribute of my `UserPrice` model  with the date of my `:all_dates` field. The reason for this is so user's don't have to change the `:purchase_date` of all of the user_price records they want to create on the form (they can create a maximum of 5), so what it suppose to do is update the columns of the user_prices with the date that is given from the `:all_dates` field.

---

**Problem**

Unfortunately on creating 1 to 5 records of user_prices, I get a NoMethodError because of the `:all_dates` field:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `user_prices' for #<UserPrice:0x485d918>):
  app/models/user_price.rb:54:in `save_all_dates_to_user_prices'
  app/controllers/user_prices_controller.rb:27:in `each'
  app/controllers/user_prices_controller.rb:27:in `create_multiple'
```

**UPDATE**

I got rid of the NoMethodError by putting this in my UserPrice model:

```
def user_prices
  @user_prices = Array.new() { UserPrice.new } 
end
```

But that isn't correct because the `:all_dates` field doesn't update my UserPrice `:purchase_date` fields. Does anyone have any ideas?

---

**Question**

How do I define the method `user_prices`? 
I am guessing its suppose to be able to loop several new records of UserPrice but how is that done?

---

**Code**

This form acts like a nested form but instead of using two or more models its just using one single model which is my UserPrice to generate more records on the form, in my case being 5 new ones.

```
<%= form_tag create_multiple_user_prices_path, :method => :post do %>
 <%= date_select("user_price", "all_dates"  %>
   <% @user_prices.each_with_index do |user_price, index| %>
      <%= fields_for "user_prices[#{index}]", user_price do |up| %>
          <%= render "add_store_price_fields", :f => up %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

```
  class UserPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :price, :product_name, :all_dates
  attr_accessor :all_dates
  after_save :save_all_dates_to_user_prices

  protected

  def save_all_dates_to_user_prices
      self.user_prices.each {|up| up.purchase_date = self.all_dates if up.new_record?}
  end
```

---

```
class UserPricesController < ApplicationController

  def new
     @user_prices = Array.new(5) { UserPrice.new }
  end

  def create_multiple
    @user_prices = params[:user_prices].values.collect { |up| UserPrice.new(up) }
    if @user_prices.all?(&:valid?)
      @user_prices.each(&:save!)
      redirect_to :back, :notice => "Successfully added prices."
    else
      redirect_to :back, :notice => "Error, please try again."
    end
  end
```

Comment: One problem I see: The first argument to `date_select` needs to be the name of a object (your user_price), the second should be `all_dates`. Also, see what the generated HTML looks like ?

Comment: @Zabba Thanks, I believe it is correct now, check out my editing now. The error is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Took a totally different approach and was still able to get the same results in this Question: [How to update a model's attribute with a virtual attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805352/how-to-update-a-models-attribute-with-a-virtual-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

Re: Why receiving error **undefined method `user_prices' for...**

Ans: You need to define the method `user_prices`

Since you named the model (object) UserPrice, normally user_price would be used to represent an instance of the model.

You need to re-think what user_prices represents, an array of UserPrice objects/records? Or something else?

**Added** Do you want method `save_all_dates_to_user_prices` to iterate through all of the `UserPrice` records?

If so, then:

- You probably want `save_all_dates_to_user_prices` to be a class method since it would be dealing with the multiple instances of the class.
- The method would need to first load an array with all of the current records. Do this with the class method find or [scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html)